# Problem in case using multiple favicons in same domain

Tags: browser, mobile-safari, mobile-website, favicon, bookmarks

We have 'abc.com' and users have their own page with 'abc.com/userid'

Users set favicon for thier page, and published.

But some browsers(iOS Safari) replace all favicons in bookmarks which already exist

This is step:

1. I add bookmark 'abc.com/user1' with favicon 'user1.png'
2. I add bookmark 'abc.com/user2' with favicon 'user2.png'
3. Both bookmark image are same 'user2.png'

I can't find spec about it.
I want to know whether favicon is unique for domain or not

Thanks

Comment: Interesting issue. Could you edit your question to indicate how you declare the icons? (ie. the HTML line(s) in both pages)

Comment: @philippe_b - I am running into the same issue as the question author.  I am dynamically adding the apple-touch-icon via javascript based on the path.  So in the authors example:  'abc.com/user1' I am adding the icon like this: `<link rel='apple-touch-icon' href='user1.png' />`.  This does not work correctly on an iPad (intended target) but it does work correctly in Chrome if I change the the rel to `rel='shortcut icon`.  Any guidance would be greatly appreciated

Comment: @Jason Your code is missing in your comment.

Comment: @philippe_b - this is the javascript code I am using: <br/> `document.title = this.storeState.business.name;<br/>document.head || (document.head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0]);<br/>var link = document.createElement('link');<br/>link.rel = 'apple-touch-icon';<br/>link.href = '/images/icons/' + this.storeState.business.faviconUrl;<br/>document.head.appendChild(link);`

Comment: apologies for no line breaks, having a tough time formatting this one - pls ignore the line break tags...

Comment: I never played with favicon and JS, so I'm of little help here. First thing I would do: look for existing reference to find out if this really works or not. I wouldn't be surprised if that wouldn't work, even if everything is okay regarding DOM.

Comment: @philippe_b - after much research and trying a lot of different things, I don't think it is possible to create a dynamically changing apple-touch-icon via javascript.  I was midway through posting my research / what I have tried as the answer but then I realized that isn't even the question Minsu was asking :/  If you should happen to stumble across a solution for dynamically changing apple-touch-icons in the future, please do let me know.  Thanks!

Comment: I'm sorry it didn't work in the end. If I learn anything I'll post it here.